# How to access a button from another xml that is not set in setContentView?

Tags: java, android

For example, if I have a java class that has setContentView(R.layout.page), I can only access the buttons and textboxes from within the page xml, in that java class. But how do you access buttons from other xml layouts from the same java class without doing setContentView()? When I attempt to do this, I get a nullPointerException. Thanks in advance for any replies. (I would happily provide any required information)

Comment: What is your purpose to do that?

Comment: My purpose is to change an image in "x" xml layout, from the clicking of one button in "y" xml layout.

Comment: so your "x" xml layout in others activity?

Comment: you can using intent or shared preference to transfer command and data between the activities

Comment: Ok so, I have "Bacon" image from "x" xml. When I click a "Pig" button from "y" xml, I want to change "Bacon" into "Pig". What I did was set an onClickListner for "Pig", and when that is pressed, I made an Image variable, set it to "Bacon", use setImageResource and set "Bacon" into "Pig", but that resulted a nullReferenceException, so I want to know another way so that it doesn't trigger that error

Comment: The layout with the bacon image would not be visible in the current activity anyways, so what's the point? In the current activity you should save a state from the pig button onClick and pass that state in the intent to the activity that contains the bacon image, so when that activity starts, you can use this state to set the bacon or pig image appropriately.

Comment: @pinkydoe : Use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) for accessing views from other layouts which you are using in current Activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use LayoutInflator if xml y is also a part of your current activity

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
                 View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.y, null );
ImageView img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```